# localhost uses an invalid security certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am trying to enable SSL locally in my Linux machine. For this I followed [this tutorial](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html) where I create a certificate authority, an intermediate certificate authority and lastly the certificate for localhost and its key. I verified each step and all files seems to be fine.

I used the a conf file with alternate_names as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288517/how-to-make-self-signed-certificate-for-localhost).

```
# OpenSSL intermediate CA configuration file.
# Copy to `/root/ca/intermediate/openssl.cnf`.

[ ca ]
# `man ca`
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
# Directory and file locations.
dir               = /home/cquiros/data/projects2017/climmob/software/climmob/ssl/ca/intermediate
certs             = $dir/certs
crl_dir           = $dir/crl
new_certs_dir     = $dir/newcerts
database          = $dir/index.txt
serial            = $dir/serial
RANDFILE          = $dir/private/.rand

# The root key and root certificate.
private_key       = $dir/private/intermediate.key.pem
certificate       = $dir/certs/intermediate.cert.pem

# For certificate revocation lists.
crlnumber         = $dir/crlnumber
crl               = $dir/crl/intermediate.crl.pem
crl_extensions    = crl_ext
default_crl_days  = 30

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md        = sha256

name_opt          = ca_default
cert_opt          = ca_default
default_days      = 375
preserve          = no
policy            = policy_loose

[ policy_strict ]
# The root CA should only sign intermediate certificates that match.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of `man ca`.
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ policy_loose ]
# Allow the intermediate CA to sign a more diverse range of certificates.
# See the POLICY FORMAT section of the `ca` man page.
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
# Options for the `req` tool (`man req`).
default_bits        = 2048
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
string_mask         = utf8only

# SHA-1 is deprecated, so use SHA-2 instead.
default_md          = sha256

# Extension to add when the -x509 option is used.
x509_extensions     = v3_ca

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request>.
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
localityName                    = Locality Name
0.organizationName              = Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name
commonName                      = Common Name
emailAddress                    = Email Address

# Optionally, specify some defaults.
countryName_default             = GB
stateOrProvinceName_default     = England
localityName_default            =
0.organizationName_default      = Alice Ltd
organizationalUnitName_default  =
emailAddress_default            =

[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical intermediate CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign

[ usr_cert ]
# Extensions for client certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = client, email
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, emailProtection

[ server_cert ]
# Extensions for server certificates (`man x509v3_config`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

[ crl_ext ]
# Extension for CRLs (`man x509v3_config`).
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ ocsp ]
# Extension for OCSP signing certificates (`man ocsp`).
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = critical, OCSPSigning

[ alternate_names ]
DNS.1       = climmob.net
DNS.1       = localhost
DNS.3       = localhost.localdomain
DNS.4       = 127.0.0.1
```

Lastly my apache conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/srv/httpd/htdocs"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/climmob.net.cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/climmob.net.key.nc.pem"
#SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/ca-chain.cert.pem"
SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/ca-chain.cert.pem"

...
```

I have tried to go to the steps over and over again. But nothing seems to work. Any idea what else do I need to do?

Comment: `nothing seems to work.`.  Can you describe your problem with more detail?    That's not much to go on.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a self-signed certificate. Those certificates generate invalid certificate warnings in browsers, because the certificates are not signed by any trusted certificate issuer.

Browsers do not trust self-signed certificates because it breaks the security model of TLS / SSL.